# Put every POST and GET requests on hold except one specific, then continue

Tags: php, ajax

I need only PHP answers.

Setup : Apache Server and PHP version 7.4.

I'm working on a CAPTCHA plugin for WordPress. On that purpose, I thought I'd validate the CAPTCHA field before validating any other request.

This means I want to perform the CAPTCHA POST request **before** any other $_REQUEST is complete.

These other requests can be multiples, and I won't be able to handle their scripts.

I thought I'd detect if a POST or GET request has been made, then maybe call sleep() and perform my POST meanwhile.

The problem is : sleep() pauses the whole script whereas I only want the other POST and GET requests to be paused...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' OR $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_METHOD’] === 'GET' AND $_POST["myRequest"]) { 

    // Pause every POST and GET requests apart from $_POST["myRequest"] until $_POST["myRequest"] is performed

} else { 

    continue;

}
```

Comment: that won't scale. it also depends on how your php environment is setup

Comment: I edited my question to include my PHP environment

Comment: Your server cannot control the order in which requests are sent to it. And php cannot tell the webserver to block other requests (except by inadvertently blocking _all_ requests, perhaps, but obviously that's not desirable). Ideally your Web application should be stateless and not dependent on things happening in a specific order. If that's unavoidable, simply return an error status if other types of request occur prior to the one you want - you can have code which checks some stored data to ascertain that

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the error status could be a solution if I didn't mind if the other requests don't succeed. That's why I thought about pausing the requests instead of cancelling them. How would you block all requests ?

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem. What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: if the requests can each check some shared resource ( database record? file? ) then  when POST arrives it marks the resource in use, GETs can then check that resource and either refuse to process, or wait and recheck.

Comment: You don't want to block all requests, because that will block the one you're wanting, as well. I meant that by sleeping you could accidentally block everything if your server runs out of threads to process new incoming requests because there are so many threads sat sleeping/looping infinitely

Comment: `if I didn't mind if the other requests don't succeed`...are you saying that you do mind that? Realistically I think that you have to accept that they will need to fail. Otherwise as I said you'll end up overloading the server. All this sounds like the result of some big design flaw though...as someone said earlier its not clear why you think you need to do this - it sounds highly unusual. Perhaps if you explain the overall requirement and scenario, we can suggest a more feasible solution

Comment: I edited my question so that you understand the bigger picture. It's about CAPTCHA.

Comment: OK. Yes you just need to reject all other requests until the captcha is validated. Or prevent the frontend from even sending them, if you can control the code in the page

Comment: That’s where you can start an authenticated session only if the captcha succeeds. Then require that on other requests

Answer (score 2):

You could use session and keep track of the request and save the request if $_POST['myRequest'] is not present, than load the previous request from session or a file. Like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' OR $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_METHOD’] === 'GET') { 

   // POST myRequest has been done before
if(isset($_SESSION['.my-request.lock'])) {

    // If present remove it
    unset($_SESSION['.my-request.lock']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['my-data.json'])) {
        $my_prev_request = json_decode( $_SESSION['my-data.json'] );

        unset($_SESSION['my-data.json']);
    }

    // Process other requests

} else {

    if(isset($_POST['myRequest'])) {

        $_SESSION['.my-request.lock'] = true;

        // Do your own thing

    } else {
        // No myRequest and no file, save request data to load it after POST myRequest 
        $_SESSION['my-data.json'] = json_encode( $_REQUEST );
    }

}

} else { 

    // Display Error ?
    continue;

}
```

Comment: It's slightly odd to use strings that look like file names as keys in the session array, since they won't actually be separate files. I like the approach otherwise, though.

Comment: Yes it is. Actually i was using file, but i thought sessions were better and i was too lazy to change name. Please forgive me :P